# How to update all instances of an element in XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml structure as below. How can I replace the element value of  that is present everywhere in this structure? Is there a way to do this using Linq? Also, sometimes the structure could be different but there will always be Resource element so I need to look at all instances of Resource and not care about where it is present.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <Number>123456</Number>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Events>
          <Event>
            <ID>12</ID>
          </Event>
        </Events>
        <Items>
          <Item>
            <ID>12</ID>
            <Resource>Replace this value</Resource>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <ID>13</ID>
            <Resource>Replace this value</Resource>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <ID>14</ID>
            <Resource>Replace this value</Resource>
          </Item>
        </Items>
    </User>

    //More User elements where Resource needs to be updated
    <User>
    </User>

    <User>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Comment: Update them how? For each user? All of them to the same value? Depending on another value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq is a query language, so you can't directly use it to modify the value, but you can easily select all the `Resource` elements in the document with it and iterate/change them.

For example:

```
// or load from xml, however you have it
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\myxml.xml"); 
// iterate every Resource element
foreach (XElement element in xDoc.Descendants("Resource"))            
    element.Value = "Hello, world";
```

That will pick out every `Resource` element in the XML regardless of where it is in the hierarchy, which in your case, is what you need. If you needed to target it more specifically, you could either use an XPath expression or further Linq calls such as `Element()` which work on a single level of the hierarchy.